# Canon 5D Mark IV - 4K Crop Factor

Tags: canon, video, crop-factor, canon-5d-mark-iv

The Canon 5D Mark IV was launched with a [crop factor of 1.74X](https://www.usa.canon.com/learning/training-articles/training-articles-list/video-features-in-the-eos-5d-mark-iv) back in 2016.

Is this crop factor now lower thanks to a firmware upgrade as was [rumoured back in 2017](https://petapixel.com/2017/03/29/canon-5d-mark-iv-firmware-update-reduce-4k-crop-1-74x-1-27x/)?

The official [spec sheet](https://downloads.canon.com/nw/camera/products/eos/5d-mark-iv/specifications/canon-eos-5d-mark-iv-with-canon-log-specifications-chart.pdf?cm_mmc=nw-_-eos-5d-mark-iv-_-specifications-_-download) does not mention any crop factor.

Comment: This question is about video in a context that is not likely to be relevant to still photography. https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/can-i-ask-videography-related-questions/291#291

Comment: If it hasn't already been answered there, this question is probably a better fit for [Video SE](https://video.stackexchange.com)

Comment: See also: https://youtu.be/vzA9kmxCZl4

Answer (score -1):

The "crop factor" of a camera is the ratio of the physical size of the sensor to the size of a 35mm film negative (24x36mm). To change the crop ratio of a camera you would have to replace the sensor (at least to reduce it, some firmware could throw away pixels to increase it).

Comment: The OP talk about crop for 4K video, so physical crop factor have nothing to do.